# How to load a file with one- dimension in python?

Tags: python

I try to load numpy files from my folder

```
path ='C:\\Users\\user\\folder'

traces= os.listdir(path)

for file in files:

    filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
    dataArray= np.load(filepath)
    print (dataArray)
```

The result of one file is:

```
[[-0.01511072 -0.01470489 -0.01428879 ..., -0.01206957 -0.01214663
  -0.01222625]]
```

However I need to have:

```
[-0.01511072 -0.01470489 -0.01428879 ..., -0.01206957 -0.01214663
  -0.01222625]
```

How to resolve the problem please?

Comment: `print(dataArray[0])`?

Comment: What would be the expected result for 2 files?

Comment: @SergeBallesta [ [-0.01511072 -0.01470489 -0.01428879 ..., -0.01206957 -0.01214663
  -0.01222625],  [-0.01511072 -0.01470489 -0.01428879 ..., -0.01206957 -0.01214663
  -0.01222625]]